# OMI data projection not lining up with WGS84

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap

I am using data from Aura's OMI of global NO2. I need to compare values of NO2 measurements from OMI with measurements from ground based stations, for which the pixel location needs to be matching with the ground based stations location. However, my data layers do not line up (see image). [image]

The coordinate system of the shapefile (world) is WGS 84 with datum World Geodetic System 1984. The coordinate system of the .tif file is GCS_WGS_1984 with datum D_World_Geodetic_System_1984. Trying to reproject a layer results in error 000365 "Invalid geographic transformation".

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Does the raster report its extent as +/-180? Because it's not quite (ex. NZ is missing), which is not helping.

Comment: Mkennedy, I noticed the NZ issue also and fixed that. The extent of the raster is reported as Left: 0, Top: 720, Bottom: 0, Right: 1440, which is the same as the number of columns (1440) and rows (720). The